# Multiple values in Oracle SOA BPEL Assignment

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel, oracle-soa, oracle-bpm-suite

I want to assign multiple values to single element in Oracle BPEL assignment so I can make desired payload on run-time like I did in SOAP UI.

[image]

I have tried various functions in BPEL assignment: Copy, CopyList, InsertAfter but I am not able to create same payload :

[image]

Comment: you can use a transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create an array of values. Replace the part

```
ns6:group/ns6:item/ns6:value
```

with

```
ns6:group/ns6:item[1]/ns6:value
ns6:group/ns6:item[2]/ns6:value
```

Its also explained in this blog:
http://sathyam-soa.blogspot.nl/2016_07_01_archive.html